# How to change Facebook username to the previous one

Tags: facebook, username

I had changed my Facebook username (once) and Facebook doesn't allow me to change it twice. So I want to change it back to the old one. Is this possible? Or, are there any methods to change the username twice?

Answer (score 2):

According to Facebook's [username guidelines](https://www.facebook.com/help/105399436216001):

> Choose a username you'll be happy with for the long term. Usernames
>   are not transferable and you can only change your username once.

Comment: But if there was Only one character mistake in your FB username, you Wont be happy. so i have to delete my FB account just for a character ?! it's sadly !